# Format attempts to (horizontal) date axis constantly overridden

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

In Python, using XlsxWriter, I created a line chart in which the horizontal axis is date (I verified that, in the underlying data, the column is indeed numeric/date).

The resulting chart set dates 11-14 periods (days) apart and when I tried various methods (including 'date_axis': True) to format the axis to only display the first of each month, it was ignored/overridden.

Date column is daily, 429 rows. See image.

How can I override the override?

Here is the relevant code snippet.

```css
# Access the workbook and worksheet objects
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['PVT - Daily activity']

# Create a chart object
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})

# Configure the series for 'Totals per date'
chart.add_series({
    'name': 'Totals per date',
    'categories': ['PVT - Daily activity', 1, 0, len(pivot_table), 0],
    'values': ['PVT - Daily activity', 1, 1, len(pivot_table), 1],
})

# Set the chart title and axis labels
chart.set_title({'name': 'Daily Activity'})
chart.set_x_axis({'name': 'Date'})
chart.set_y_axis({'name': 'Totals per date'})

# Set the legend position to the bottom of the chart
chart.set_legend({'position': 'bottom'})

# Set the horizontal axis to display only the dates that are the first of each month
chart.set_x_axis({
    'major_gridlines': {'visible': False},
    'major_tick_mark': 'none',
    'minor_tick_mark': 'none',
    'num_font': {'color': 'black'},
    'num_format': '[$-en-US,101]mmm d, yyyy;@',
    'date_axis': True,
    'tick_label_position': 'low',
    'major_unit': 1,
    'major_unit_type': 'months',
    'base_unit': 'days',
})
```

[image]

Comment: A demonstration of your code would be more informative. Please add the code to the question.

Comment: So I showed you an example of how you can build a line chart on data that’s selected by a condition.
I hope my answer will help you.

Comment: I solved the issue, but as the post is closed, I cannot show the code. In any case, I apologize for taking your time and thank you @SVBazuev!

Answer (score 1):

*Since XlsxWriter takes a range of values to use some of the 429 rows,*
*the selected ones must be allocated to a separate range.*

***For example:***

```py
import xlsxwriter


workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('chart_data.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(name='MySheet1')
bold = workbook.add_format({"bold": 1})

headings = ["Date", "Value", "Select Date", "Trend"]

worksheet.write_row("A1", headings, bold)

_data = {
    '01.01.2022': 100,
    '02.01.2022': 200,
    '01.02.2022': 150,
    '03.02.2022': 180,
    '01.03.2022': 120,
    '04.03.2022': 220
}

date_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'dd.mm.yyyy'})


counter = 1
for row_num, (date_, value) in enumerate(_data.items()):
    row_num += 1
    worksheet.write(row_num, 0, date_, date_format)
    worksheet.write(row_num, 1, value)
    if date_.startswith('01.'):
        worksheet.write(counter, 2, date_, date_format)
        worksheet.write(counter, 3, value)
        counter += 1


chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})

chart.set_drop_lines()

chart.add_series({
    "name": "=%s!$D$1" % (worksheet.name),
    'categories': '=%s!$C$2:$C$%d' % (worksheet.name, counter),
    'values': '=%s!$D$2:$D$%d' % (worksheet.name, counter),
})

chart.set_x_axis({"date_axis": True})
worksheet.insert_chart('E1', chart)

workbook.close()
```

[image]

***Does that solve your problem?***

Comment: Thanks a lot SVBazuev! And sorry I wasn't explicit enough when I first uploaded the question!

Comment: I have just edited the original question to add the relevant code snippet.